# Strange error on EMR - Spark, while using Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, emr, parquet

I have some pretty simple queries that were running fine:

```
val toplevel_genre = airingAusDF.withColumn("toplevel_genre", explode(col("program.genres")))
val toplevel = toplevel_genre.groupBy("toplevel_genre.name").count().sort(desc("count")).take(10)
```

With migration of input to Parquet format, I am facing a strange stack-trace. It seems to work fine with English data. With data in other languages, I encounter this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 2023.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 2023.0 (TID 17158, ip-172-31-12-157.us-west-2.compute.internal): java.lang.ClassCastException: optional binary element (UTF8) is not a group
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.Type.asGroupType(Type.java:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetReadSupport$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetReadSupport$$clipParquetType(ParquetReadSupport.scala:131)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am currently having a similar problem